# What plant is this mini christmas tree?

Tags: identification

Would you know what species does this tiny "Christmas tree" belong to? No info on the label.
[image]
[image: den]

Comment: A close up photo of a branch clearly showing the needles and their arrangement round the stem would help with ID but it looks like it might be Abies nordmanniana.  Are the tips of the needles blunt or pointed?

Comment: @Bamboo that would be the tiniest a. nordmanniana ever? Judging by the magazine(?) and card, the needles are what, 5mm? Juniper, maybe?

Comment: @Stephie no, not Juniper - the radial arrangement and length of the needles is wrong, and I'm not seeing any awl like juvenile leaves further in either. All plants are small initially, even nordmann fir! But I still want a close up of a stem....

Comment: Sharp needles would indicate spruce , blunt would likely be fir ( as commented) or Douglas fir ( not actually a fir) . The location would help. Trees can be pretty small : I once smuggled a few 2 inch Alberta Spruce into the US = they lived.

Comment: The "needles" are pointed and flat (more like very narrow leaves). @Bamboo, I have got it at Marks and Spencer for £5, if it could be of any indication.

Comment: Doesn't help to know M&S were selling it- its not on sale now unfortunately. All that white stuff that's been sprayed on it doesn't help with ID, but its not Abies if the needles are pointed. I'm now thinking it might be Cunninghamia lanceolata, the chinese fir, not fully hardy in the UK outdoors, though the leaves look just a fraction thick - the green stem fits though. Cunninghamia is unusual, not commonly available, so it wouldn't be surprising if M&S were selling them as 'posh'  mini xmas trees

Comment: I would be easier to recognise without the horticultural paint on the needles.  It could definitely be a dwarf Cunninghamami.  There are also many many dwarf cultivated fir.  When I use to do the ordering for a nursery, we would bring in many dwarf varieties.  It could be Abies concolor 'Archer's Dwarf'.  Can you get us a picture of one of the low limbs with little to no paint?

Comment: It doesn't look much like a regular Abies concolor ( my favorite conifer). It does not look like any spruce.

Comment: Thank you! I will look after my plant as if it's Cunninghamia.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Your right.  It's not.

Comment: I sent an email of your pictures to a conifer grower I know.